# bring back category and product only if all the product status is Inactive

Tags: sql

I have following sql:

```
Select c.category, p.product, p.status
From category c,
     cat_prod cp,
     prod p
Where c.category_id = cp.category_id
  And cp.prod_id = p.prod.id
```

This will bring back:

```
CATEGORY PRODUCT STATUS
A        1 .     Active
A .      2 .     Inactive
B .      12 .    Inactive
B .      22 .    Inactive
C .      1 .     Inactive
D .      22 .    Inactive
D .      33 .    Active
D        44 .    Active
```

Desired Result (only if status is Inactive for all products that are associated to category, don't want to bring back category A and D since one of the status is Active)

```
CATEGORY PRODUCT STATUS
B .      12 .    Inactive
B .      22 .    Inactive
C .      1 .     Inactive
```

Thanks

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Perhaps use NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply extend it with NOT EXIST clause -

```
Select c.category, p.product, p.status
From category c
Join cat_prod cp on c.category_id = cp.category_id
Join prod p on cp.prod_id = p.prod.id
Where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM category c2 
                  JOIN cat_prod cp2 ON c2.category_id = cp2.category_id
                  JOIN prod p2 ON cp2.prod_id = p2.prod.id
                  WHERE c2.category_id = cp2.category_id
                  And cp2.prod_id = p2.prod.id
                  AND c2.category_id = c.category_id
                  AND p2.status = 'Active');
```

Comment: Hi Ankit,  I thought that this gave me the answer, but just noticed that this will bring back Category A Product 2 Status Inactive.  This record should not come back because this Category A also has Product 1 that has Active Status.  If one of the Products for the Category is Active, I didn't want to show that Category altogether.

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks, that worked, but just had one question, I noticed that the join condition is repeated in the not exists query ( c2.category_id = cp2.category_id is repeated, same with cp2.prod_id = p2.prod_id)  just curious what the reason for putting same join condition in twice?  thanks

Comment: Because STATUS column is in prod table and category column is in category table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions for this:

```
select category, product, status
from (select c.category, p.product, p.status,
             sum(case when p.status <> 'inactive' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by c.category) as cnt_not_inactive
      from category c join
           cat_prod cp
           on c.category_id = cp.category_id join
           prod p
           on cp.prod_id = p.prod.id
     ) cps
where cnt_not_inactive = 0;
```

Note:  Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  Do not use commas in the `FROM` clause.

If you just wanted the categories, I would recommend aggregation:

```
select c.category
from category c join
     cat_prod cp
     on c.category_id = cp.category_id join
     prod p
     on cp.prod_id = p.prod.id
group by c.category
having min(p.status) = max(p.status) and
       min(p.status) = 'inactive'
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit and Gordon,  was trying to figure this out for few days.  Great forum to learn sql.. actually going through questions on this forum to learn.  Appreciate the quick feedback.